# How to clone an npc character's face/body as your own?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Is there a way to get a formula or set of parameters for a random npc's physical appearance? Say I want to make my character's face look like Martin or Jeoffry or a Mythic Dawn Acolyte I just slain, what would be my options?

Comment: wow, this is a great idea! +1 for coming up with a question I would have asked myself if it had previously occured to me. BTw to any possible Answer Holders - could this also or instead be performed in skyrim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://tes.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=2170) mod add numbers near sliders on character creation screen,if you know the values this makes them easy to remake.

Unfortunately there isn't any good list of NPC appearance codes online,you will have to find them out by playing with game files.

[This](http://cs.elderscrolls.com/index.php/Main_Page) is the official oblivion editing tool I would start here and check for values in desired NPC's properties,details...

[Wrye Bash](http://wryemusings.com/Wrye%20Bash.html#FaceImport) is another powerful tool for editing oblivion files,it has some face transplant option by itself but you should be looking just for values.

[This](http://tes.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=7808) and [this](http://planetelderscrolls.gamespy.com/View.php?view=oblivionmods.detail&id=2997) are 2 more things that could be of use to you,both of them use savegame files to copy the character face,you could get some hints where to look for values or even manage to directly copy npc file.